# pointer to function in c?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I m learning c (programming in ANSI c -> fifth edition) and facing the below issue:

I'm implementing one program with pointers to functions

```
#include<stdio.h>

//void swap (int *a, int *b);                      //function declaration
int main() 
{
  int m = 25;
  int n = 100;

  printf("m is %d, n is %d\n", m, n);
  swap(&m, &n);                                    //calling a function
  printf("m is %d, n is %d\n", m, n);
  return 0;

}

void swap (int *a, int *b)                         //function implementation
{
  int temp;
  temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

in the above program comment the line `void swap (int *a, int *b);` then program run file but give one suggestion here facing the issue **why here give the  suggestion**

main.c:10:3: warning: **implicit declaration of function ‘swap’** [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main.c:16:6: warning: **conflicting types for ‘swap’**
main.c:10:3: note: **previous implicit declaration of ‘swap’ was here**
m is 25, n is 100
m is 100, n is 25

when I m uncomment this line `void swap (int *a, int *b);` then program run fine

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap (int *a, int *b);                      //function declaration
int main() 
{
  int m = 25;
  int n = 100;

  printf("m is %d, n is %d\n", m, n);
  swap(&m, &n);                                    //calling a function
  printf("m is %d, n is %d\n", m, n);
  return 0;

}

void swap (int *a, int *b)                         //function implementation
{
  int temp;
  temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

problem is why not allowed this one in the above program

```
void swap (int, int);              //function declaration
```

and give the error

error:

**conflicting types for ‘swap’**
  void swap (int *a, int *b)                         //function implementation

but in book example allowed

[image]

Comment: A function must be *declared* before the point where it is used in your source file. When you comment the *declaration* for `swap` the *definition* for the function isn't until *after* `main()`. What the compiler does in that case is implicitly define `swap` for you. (this takes a bit of history of C, but the type of any object when the object type isn't defined defaults to `int`) In your case the compiler provided a default declaration of `int swap (int *a, int *b)` which conflicted with your later definition of `void swap (int *a, int *b)` -- which is why you received the warning.

Comment: For your second question, `int` is a separate type from `int*` (pointer-to-`int`), so your two declarations for the `swap` function are not at all compatible.

Comment: Please do not add text as pictures. They are no artwork. Simply copying and pasting the plain text into the question is best.

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap (int *a, int *b);
```

This here before main() is called function signature that should match function declaration
below.

```
void swap (int *a, int *b){
...
}
```

But the same function signature can be written as

```
void swap (int *, int *);
```

And not

```
void swap (int , int ); //This will result in type mismatch
```

I guess this is what you are asking.

NOTE: Forward declaration is important here which lets you declare first and define later helps maintain code readability.